# how to find the top 5 repeated values in database and get 5 results?

Tags: mysql

```
    id |  unqid
    ___|________
    1  |  v1
    2  |  v1
    3  |  v1
    4  |  v1
    5  |  v4
    6  |  v4
    7  |  v9
    8  |  v9
    9  |  v9
   10  |  v2
   11  |  v7
```

i need to get the most repeated values ,limit is 5, like 
v1
v9
v4
v2
v7

I've tried  this code but showing nothing

```
SELECT unqid, COUNT(*) TotalCount FROM votes GROUP BY unqid HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Simple SELECT DISTINCT unqid FROM votes ;-)

Comment: The query in your question looks correct (assuming the table is named `votes`).  Do you get an error?  What does "showing nothing" mean in this case?

Comment: The syntax of the query is valid. If you only want to return a maximum of 5 rows, add a `LIMIT 5` clause to the end of your query. It's not clear what question you are asking. A sample of the result set you want would help explain the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is an Oracle only thing, so appologies if this doesn't apply to you, but I would be doing that as

```
select unqid, TotalCount 
  from (
    select unqid, count(*) as TotalCount 
    from votes 
    group by unqid
    order by TotalCount desc
  )
where TotalCount > 1
```

Comment: In standard SQL (and also in MySQL which is what the OP tagged the question), you can't put `WHERE` after `GROUP BY`. The `WHERE` clause in your example should be a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Yep, I fixed my syntax, and ran a query that appeared to work.

Comment: How does the result set returned by this query differ from the result set returned by OP query?